# I want a way to send messages on WhatsApp using Twilio without using Sandox. Could you help me find a solution for it?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, twilio

I am making an alert app for a very small company which does not have a Facebook Business Page nor a website which I could link to get the WhatsApp API. Could you please suggest me an alternative way through which I could make use of Twilio but avoid using sandbox. I have been making this project for around a year now and still not able to solve the issue successfully. Please help me solve this problem.
I am also including the code snippet below for reference.

```
import pandas as pd
from twilio.rest import Client 
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta

values=variables
df=pd.DataFrame(values)
df.drop(index=df.index[0], 
        axis=0, 
        inplace=True)
df.index = df.index-1



df['AMC_Start_Date']=df['AMC_Start_Date'].apply(lambda x:x.replace('/','-'))
df['AMC_End_Date']=df['AMC_End_Date'].apply(lambda x:x.replace('/','-'))


d1=date.today()
d1=pd.to_datetime(d1)


d2=df['AMC_Start_Date']
d2=pd.to_datetime(d2)
df['AMC_Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["AMC_Start_Date"])
df['AMC_End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["AMC_End_Date"])


d2=df['AMC_Start_Date']
d3=df['AMC_End_Date']
t=d1-d2
s=d1-d3


account_sid=‘’
auth_token = 'a7' 
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token) 
def alert2(): 
  from datetime import date, timedelta 

  dt = date.today() - timedelta(856) 
  t2=df['AMC_Start_Date'] 
  t2=pd.to_datetime(t2,format='%Y-%m-%d') 
  t3=df['AMC_End_Date'] 
  t3=pd.to_datetime(t3,format='%Y-%m-%d') 
  dt1=date.today()-timedelta(989) 
  num=['whatsapp:+9198--------','whatsapp:+91900-------']
  i1=[i for i, e in enumerate(df['AMC_Start_Date']) if e == dt]
  i2=[i for i, e in enumerate(df['AMC_End_Date']) if e == dt1]
  NULL=[]
  for j in range(len(num)):
    if i1!=NULL and i2!=NULL:
      strings1 = [str(integer) for integer in i1]
      a_string = "". join(strings1)
      an_integer = int(a_string)
      a=df['Name_and_Address'][an_integer]
      strings2 = [str(integer) for integer in i2]
      a_string2 = "". join(strings2)
      an_integer2 = int(a_string2)
      b=df['Name_and_Address'][an_integer2]
      body='Servicing scheduled today for {}'.format(a) 
      message = client.messages.create( from_='whatsapp:+141--------', body=body, to=num[j])
      body='The service ends after two days for {}'.format(b) 
      message = client.messages.create( from_='whatsapp:+141-------', body=body, to=num[j])
    elif i1!=NULL:
      strings1 = [str(integer) for integer in i1]
      a_string = "". join(strings1)
      an_integer = int(a_string)
      a=df['Name_and_Address'][an_integer]
      body='Servicing scheduled today for {}'.format(a) 
      message = client.messages.create( from_='whatsapp:+141-------', body=body, to=num[j])
    elif i2!=NULL:
      strings2 = [str(integer) for integer in i2]
      a_string2 = "". join(strings2)
      an_integer2 = int(a_string2)
      b=df['Name_and_Address'][an_integer2]
      body='The service ends after two days for {}'.format(b) 
      message = client.messages.create( from_='whatsapp:+141------', body=body, to=num[j])
    else:
      body='There are no tasks scheduled for today' 
      message = client.messages.create( from_='whatsapp:+141-------', body=body, to=num[j])
alert2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The only way to use the WhatsApp API in production with your own number and no sandbox limits is to [follow the instructions in the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/connect-number-business-profile). The instructions don't say that you need a Facebook Page or website. You do need:

- a [Facebook Business Manager account](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1710077379203657?id=180505742745347)
- to complete [Facebook Business Verification](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2058515294227817?id=180505742745347)

Once you have done those parts, you should [start your application by filling in this form](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp/request-access).

Without a Facebook Business Manager account, you cannot use the API. If you can't create one of those, then I do not know of a way that you can use the API.

Comment: I have a Facebook business id now but no website of the organisation. Any way to get around that?

Comment: It is likely best to talk to [the sales team](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) who can guide you through this process in a more manual way that perhaps avoids needing a website.